# Order Mysql Value Listing by Amount

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, mysql

I have this database with a table and a row called 'rank'.

In that database table there are 2 teams. Each Get ranked every day.

Ex.

Day 1.

Team F - rank =1
Team R - rank =2

Day 2.

Team R - rank =1
Team F - rank =2

---

So i want the teams to appear on top because of their higher rank

Right now I got this: (appear as entered)-`while($person = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {`

So what do I put in that code in order to make it be the highest value of a column.

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you be more specific about your table layout? Maybe provide the `CREATE TABLE` SQL that was used to create it?

To order results by value, you can end a sql query with `ORDER BY column_name DESC` in order to get the results returned in MAX -> MIN order of that column. You can replace `DESC` with `ASC` to get it to go in MIN -> MAX order. If you don't put `DESC` or `ASC` it defaults to one of them, but I forget which.

If you want to sort on more than one column, put them in the `ORDER BY` as comma separated. So `ORDER BY column1, column2 DESC` will produce a listing that is ordered from the greatest value of `column1` to the least value, and anytime the values of `column1` are identical between rows, it will orders those by `column2`.

If I read your question correctly, and you in fact have a "row" named rank, then something is wrong with your table structure, as you can't really name "rows" (and SQL generally refers to rows as records, anyway).

Comment: The default sort order is ascending.

Comment: THANKS!! I FOUND OUT TOO THAT IN PHPMYADMIN YOU COULD CHANGE THAT IN -OPERATIONS->ALTER TABLE ORDER BY-- SO YEA!....sry if I confused you.. I made the question very fast :D (i have a field named rank :D)

Answer (score 1):

Add an order clause at the end of your query.

Something like:

```
ORDER BY day DESC, RANK asc
```

Comment: THANKS!! I FOUND OUT TOO THAT IN PHPMYADMIN YOU COULD CHANGE IN THAT IN -OPERATIONS->ALTER TABLE ORDER BY-- ... or put those lines in run sql query... thnx!